# Querying parent category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

I have following query now:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT c.Name as CategoryName, SUM(Amount) OVER(partition by c.Name order by c.Name) as Total
    FROM Statements s
    LEFT JOIN Categories c on c.Id = s.CategoryId
    WHERE Date >= '2016-01-01'
    ORDER BY c.Name
```

It works so far and gets every category with its total amount but what I need is the following.

The categories can have child categories. I want to get the sum over every root category and all its child categories for every row.

Means category A has childs B and C. I want to get the sum over all entries in `Statements` which have category A, B or C.

The category table consists of following columns: `Id, Name, ParentId`.

The statements table consists of following coluimns: `Id, Date, Amount, CategoryId`

Sample data of table category:

```
Id, Name, ParentId
1, A, null,
2, B, 1
3, C, 2
4, D, null
```

Sample data of table Statements

```
Id, Date, Amount, CategoryId
1, 2016-01-01, 100, 1
2, 2016-01-01, 200, 2
3, 2016-01-01, 800, 4
4, 2016-01-01, 300, 3
```

The output of the query should be as follows:

```
CategoryName, Total
A, 600
D, 800
```

Ideally I could pass the parentCategoryId into the where clause which is in my sample `null` but could also be 2 for instance.

Any hints appreciated :)

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without knowing your table structures. Sample data and expected output would also probably be very useful. You should check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomH Thanks for your input, added sample data.

Comment: Is the `ParentId` in the `Category` table actually a category name? Also, does the category tree only go one level deep or can a subcategory contain its own subcategories?

Comment: @TomH No it is the Id of the category. The category tree goes in fact infinite levels deep

Comment: You should fix that in the question then, because you're currently showing names in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way is to use a recursive CTE to build the hierarchy..

```
;
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT  [Id],
            [Name],
            [ParentId],
            [Name] AS [Root]
    FROM    Categories
    WHERE   ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.[Id],
            c.[Name],
            c.[ParentId],
            [Root]
    FROM    Categories c
            JOIN cte ON c.ParentID = cte.Name
    )
SELECT  cte.[Root] AS [CategoryName],
        SUM(Amount) AS [Total]
FROM    cte
JOIN    Statements s ON s.CategoryId = cte.Id
GROUP BY cte.[Root]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question (which as I write this lacks sufficient information about how the parent/child relationship is described in the data).  But, the query is just not the right query for the OP's stated purpose.  The right query is a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT c.Name as CategoryName, SUM(Amount) as Total
FROM Table s LEFT JOIN
     Categories c 
     on c.Id = s.CategoryId
WHERE Date >= '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY c.Name
ORDER BY c.Name;
```

I would be quite surprised if the query in the question actually produced useful results, given the duplicated rows for each category.